# Extract part of cell to another cell if condition is met VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hey just getting started with VBA.
I want to make a function that extracts certain part of a cell if another cell meets some condition else it should look for another consition and those extract a different part of the cell and so on.

Thinking the IFELSE function will do just fine, but I dont know how to write the proper syntax. This is what I got so far, I have no clue of this is right:

```
Function GetSrn(CellRef1, CellRef2) As String

Dim Result As String

If Mid(CellRef1, 1, 6).Value = "Lenovo" Then

Right(CellRef2, 8) = Result

ElseIf

End If

End Function
```

CellRef1 could be "Lenovo ThinkPad T440"

CellRef 2 could be "20BUS1234567KDJI786"

Here I would like to extract "7KDJI786" to a result cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example, like so

```
Function GetSrn(CellRef1, CellRef2) As String

Dim Result As String

If Left(CellRef1, 6).Value = "Lenovo" Then
    GetSrn = Right(CellRef2, 8).Value
    'ElseIf
End If

End Function
```

You assign your function name to the result and then use it as a normal worksheet formula, e.g. `=GetSrn(a1,a2)`.